# Using chain rule and inverse function theorem simultaneously

Tags: calculus, inverse-function, chain-rule

I have a function

$h(x) = f(x-\beta b)-g(x)$

and I want to compute
$\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}(h^{-1}(x)[0])$

meaning that if $h(x_m)=0$, I want to compute $\frac{\partial x_m}{\partial \beta}$.

Can I use the inverse function theorem to do it like this?
 $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}(h^{-1}(x)[0])=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial h(x)}{\partial\beta}|_{x=x_m}}=\frac{1}{-b \frac{df(x)}{dx}|_{x=x_m-\beta b}} $$

I tried to do it by Wolfram Mathematica and got 
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}(h^{-1}(x)[0]) = (-bf'(x-\beta b)(h^{-1})'(f(x-\beta b)-g(x))[0]$$

but I would really like to simplify it further to express in in derivatives of $f$. I assume differentiability of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the implicit function theorem (which is closely related to the inverse function theorem) to calculate this. First write $h$ explicitly as function of two variables:
$$
h(x,\beta) = f(x - \beta b) - g(x).
$$
Now, you're looking for a function $x = x_m(\beta)$ that solves
$$
h(x_m(\beta),\beta) = 0.
$$
The implicit function theorem tells you that $x_m$ exists in a small neighborhood of a point $x_0,\beta_0$ where $h(x_0,\beta_0) = 0$, that $x_m$ is $C^1$ (assuming $f,g$ are $C^1$, not just differentiable), and finally that the derivative of $x_m$ is given by
$$
x_m'(\beta) = -\big(D_1 h(x_m(\beta),\beta)\big)^{-1} \cdot D_2 h(x_m(\beta),\beta),
$$
where $D_i h$ denotes the derivative of $h$ with respect to the $i$-th argument (this notation creates less ambiguity than partial derivatives).
With this formula you can explicitly calculate $x_m'$ (although you may not find an explicit expression for $x_m$ itself).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still a bit confused about notations... Does $(D_1 h(x_m(\beta),\beta ))$  mean $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x }(f(x-\beta b ) +g(x))|_{x=x_m(\beta)}))$? And also, if I need to compute the inverse, at which point?

Comment: Indeed, that's what it means. The problem with your notation is that $x$ is a dummy variable which can very easily be mistaken with other variables. For example in $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y_0)|_{x=x_0}$ you can simply replace $x$ by $y$ and the meaning does not change. But when you write a bit more sloppily $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x_0,y_0$, then changing $x$ to $y$ seems to change which partial derivative you take. The notation is used prevents this ambiguity.

Comment: The inverse (only as a matrix, which is 1x1 in your case, not the function) has to be calculated at the point $(x_m(\beta),\beta)$ as indicated. This requires knowing the inverse function $x_m$, or at least its value at the point you want to know $x_m'(\beta)$.

Comment: Thanks! So the inverse means in this case, for 1x1 matrix, just $\frac{1}{D_1 h(\dots)}$? This is much better than computing the inverse function of the derivative...